# Jquery is not allowing line breaks in text areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textarea, newline

I'm having a weird issue. When adding support for Jquery 1.7.2, I am unable to add line-breaks to textareas in forms. When I click, enter, nothing happens.

I fiddled with the source code in jquery, and found that if I commented out the following code (on line 4845)

```
for ( var type in Expr.match ) {
    Expr.match[ type ] = new RegExp( Expr.match[ type ].source + (/(?![^\[]*\])(?![^\(]*\))/.source) );
    Expr.leftMatch[ type ] = new RegExp( /(^(?:.|\r|\n)*?)/.source + Expr.match[ type ].source.replace(/\\(\d+)/g, fescape) );
}
```

the ability to add line breaks was restored. I'm not seeing anyone else having this issue, so I'm guessing something else is going on. However, my question is: what is the purpose of the code above (I'm not very javascript-savvy), and does removing it pose any risk? I'd like to just remove the code and restore line break ability to textareas, but don't want to bork the site unknowingly. I did notice that after doing this, I'm seeing an error in the js console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined -- jquery.js:4185
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Here is some code sample. The html:

```
    <form class="form-input" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <ol>
      <li>
          <label for="activity_type_id">Activity Type&nbsp;<em>*</em></label>
          <select name="activity_type_id"><option value="17" label="Call">Call</option><option value="23" label="Connectivity Meeting">Connectivity Meeting</option><option value="22" label="Conversation">Conversation</option><option value="16" label="Email (incoming)">Email (incoming)</option><option value="15" label="Email (outgoing)">Email (outgoing)</option><option value="19" label="Implementation Notes">Implementation Notes</option><option value="20" label="Meeting Minutes">Meeting Minutes</option><option value="18" label="Task">Task</option><option value="21" label="Tip / Unusual Attribute">Tip / Unusual Attribute</option></select>      </li>    
      <li>
          <label for="summary">Summary&nbsp;<em>*</em></label>
          <input size="40" maxlength="80" id="summary" name="summary" value=""/>
      </li>   
      <li>
          <label for="details">Details&nbsp;</label>
          <textarea class="wide" name="details" id="details" rows="10" columns="80"></textarea>
      </li>
          </ol>
  </fieldset>
  <input id="submit" name="addactivity" value="Add Activity" type="submit" />
  </form>
```

And the javascript that isn't included with other plugins:

```
<script>
// Dynamic lookup of C2 companies
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $(window).keydown(function(event)
  {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) 
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
  $("#search_input").autocomplete(
  {
    source: function(request,response)
    {
      $("#loading-search").show();
      $("#no-results").hide();
      $.getJSON("/services/json/cust_search.php",request,function(data) 
      {
        response(data);
        $("#loading-search").hide();
        if (data.length == 0)
        {
          $("#no-results").show();
        } else
        {
          $("#no-results").hide();
        }
      });
    },                                              
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event,ui)
    {
      $("#search_input").hide();
      $("#search_input").val(ui.item.value);
      $("#search_source").val(ui.item.source);
      $("#search-form").submit();
    } 
  });
});
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Hide all the submenus on start.  When a non-expanded menu is clicked,
//  expand that menu while collapsing the menu above it.  If a menu is 
//  clicked when its expanded, collapse.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
$(function() 
{
//  $("dd:not(:first)").hide();
  $("dd").hide();
  $("#menu-nexmark").slideDown("fast");
  $("dt a").click(function() 
  {
    var curr_dd = $(this).parent().next();
     if (curr_dd.css("display") != "none")
    {
      $("dd:visible").slideUp("medium");
      return;
    }
    $("dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
    curr_dd.slideDown("slow");
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well... what's `jquery.js:4185`? And btw, just including jQuery does not "disable line breaks". You must be doing something that causes this. See, it's all fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/46n9a/

Comment: Perhaps you could show an example of what you're trying to do with linebreaks that isn't working.

Comment: Stuff like this is usually the sign of an improper jQuery function call in one's own code.

Comment: Can u show us your code? The HTML + JavaScript... just the piece where  the problem occurs

Comment: Sounds like you've got a rogue keypress event handler returning false somewhere... (in YOUR code, not jQuery)

Comment: Edited to include some code. Chris Francis, would you recommend searching the code for a particular keyword?

What isn't working is attempting to click the "Enter" key does nothing. It neither submits the form or creates a new line. It's like it's being blocked somehow.

Comment: Well, look at the `$(window).keydown()` event handler. Do you know what it is doing? See what happens when I include it: http://jsfiddle.net/46n9a/1/

Comment: Phew! You were right. That global $(window).keydown() event handler was the issue. Setting it to only refer to the specific divs rather than the whole page restored the functionality. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was this code:

```
$(window).keydown(function(event)
  {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) 
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Setting it to refer to only the div it impacted (an autocomplete search menu we wanted to disable the ability to click enter on), restored line break functionality everywhere else:

```
$("#somediv").keydown(function(event)
  {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) 
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
```